# Discrete math question: congruence

Tags: congruences

I am trying to solve the following question:

Determine $n$ between $0$ and $19$ such that $(2311)(3912) = n \mod 20$.

Where I am now:

(2311) = 11(mod 20)

(3912) = 12(mod 20)

Multiply the 11X12 to get 132;

So:
 (2311)(3912) = 132(mod 20)

My question is, do I need to further simplify this result or is my solution above in a generally acceptable form. Sorry if this is a really lame question, I am still learning this subject.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\begin{cases}2,311=11\pmod{20}\\{}\\
3,912=12\pmod{20}\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies 2,311\cdot3,912=11\cdot12\pmod{20}=\ldots$$

Comment: A good hint that the OP should get $n=12$.

Comment: I got to the point of (2311)(3912) = 132(mod 20); but do I need to do anything else to this answer such as further simplification if possible or this is enough?

Comment: What residue do you get when you divide $\;132\;$ by $\;20\;$ ? *That* is your best answer...and this is plain definition. Perhaps you should go over this in your otes.

Comment: So further simplification is needed until the remainder term is in the lowest value for the modulo number? I am trying to find a generalized approach to this type of problem. Thanks!!

Comment: @user401806 That's the usual point, though for any formal use you can use **any** representative of a residue class. Many authors require the smallest such residue which is non-negative.

Comment: Great feedback! Thanks so much!